# Cannot verify source code smart contract on Etherscan! PLEASE help me

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, etherscan, abiencoderv2

Link for the contract on Etherscan: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x339237da476f50777da2d04b05037a805e46fcdb

Arguments Type: String,String, uint8 ~ "FinanceToken", "MYFI", "18"

Source code: https://github.com/financeyearn/TokenErc20/blob/main/test.sol

Comment: And how exactly do you expect anyone here to be able to help you in this without the actual source code?????

Comment: I am posting it.

Comment: Hi there, here is source code https://github.com/financeyearn/TokenErc20/blob/main/test.sol

Comment: I really need your help !!! Please

Comment: Your code says `pragma solidity ^0.6.6`. Please indicate exact compiler version used.

Comment: I am sorry, i am very new with Smart contract. The version is 0.6.12+commit.27d51765

Comment: I've verified it for you. Not sure what you mean by `Arguments Type: String,String, uint8 ~ "FinanceToken", "MYFI", "18"`, but the constructor of your contract (`FinanceToken`) doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: I am sorry, I mean  " Arguments Type: String,String, uint8 ~ "FinanceToken", "MYFI", "18" " is arguments of the constructor on my contract

Comment: Please, how can you do it ! I really want to know, I have spent 2 days for this problem.

Comment: Like I said, no need to pass construction arguments in your case. I have no idea what other configuration parameters you've used in your attempt, so I obviously can't tell you what other things you may have done wrong. Next time you post a question, be sure to add all the relevant information.

Comment: So, in the contract ABI encoded fields, we just leave it blank ?

Comment: In this specific case, yes, because the constructor of the contract to be verified doesn't take any input arguments.

Comment: Thank you, I will be careful for next times. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the discussion within the comment-thread, since the constructor of the contract does not take any input arguments, you should not provide any (ABI-encoded) constructor arguments on the Etherscan Contract-Verification page:

```
contract FinanceToken is ERC20 {
    constructor ()
        ERC20('FinanceToken', 'MYFI')
        public
    {
        _mint(0x96C00412E5870e79F5Bd586F0F7e91047F497B28, 400000 * 10 ** uint(decimals()));
    }
}
```

Etherscan webpage even tells you that explicitly:

> Constructor Arguments (for contracts that were created with constructor parameters)